# Vendor asking for SSL certificates for an internal API

Tags: ssl

We are installing a new program that the vendor says will require two SSL certificates (Both internal):

Servername.Domain
and ServernameAPI.Domain

I'm using our own CA for the cert, and I have installed one on the server and have added it to IIS.

He wanted the certificates to be installed before our API is created and the software is installed but I am unsure of how to create a SSL cert for the API using ADCS. I've only ever made them for the servers themselves.

Also, would I really need a separate one for the API or would the server SSL cert work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Issue one certificate with Subject Alternative Name that includes both those names. [For AD CS, use the web enrollment form, or certreq.exe.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/931351/how-to-add-a-subject-alternative-name-to-a-secure-ldap-certificate) Certificate requests are standard, so you could also use any other x509 tools or documentation.

TLS clients check the DNS name against the certificate. So a cert only issued to, say, host `APIweb3.example.com` is not enough for requests to `API.example.com`.

Independent certificates could be useful if you wanted to separate their use or issuance. For example, if you wanted to force all API requests to come to the web server (or load balancer)  at `API.example.com`, have that be the only name on the cert.  `APIweb3.example.com` could be another cert used for remote access of that machine specifically.

Comment: I used a SAN for the API. Didn't even think of that. Thanks!